# Showing that a polynomial is primitive.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Show that $f(x)=x^2+x+3 \in \mathbb{Z}_7$ is a primitive polynomial.

I have shown that it is irreducible but I am unsure how to show that it is primitive. Any help would be great.

Comment: By which definition of primitive do you mean? Normally a primitive polynomial means its coefficients share no common nontrivial factor, but according to wikipedia there is another definition. Also please clarify on what $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is, is it the integers modulo $7$ or the $7$-adic integers? Both definitions lead to this question being meaningful strangely.

Comment: I think you do not mean primitive as defined by dinoboy

Comment: I do not believe this is the definition I am familiar with. I believe I have to show that $\alpha$ is a primitive element of F but I am not sure how to go about it. And when I say Z_7 I am taking about integers modulo $7$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F = \mathbb{Z}_7[x] / \left< f(x) \right> $ represented as degree-$1$ polynomials in $\alpha$. $|F^*| = 48$.

Now all you have to do is prove that $o(\alpha)=48$. $48=2^4 \cdot 3$, so all you have to show is that $\alpha^{24} \ne 1$ and $\alpha^{16} \ne 1$. I would recommend repeated squaring:

$$\alpha^2 = 6\alpha + 4$$
$$\alpha^4 = 5\alpha + 6$$
$$\alpha^8 = 3$$

And it's easy from here.

(I used [this](http://wims.unice.fr/wims/en_tool~algebra~calcff.en.html) calculator, which you might find useful for such computations, but it's not hard at all to square these by hand if you need to on a test.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not 100% sure how you got F*=48. Am I correct in thinking that you did $7^2-1$ ?

Comment: Yes: $F^*$ consists of all of the elements of $F$ (of which there are $7^2$) except for $0$.

Comment: So next I would calculate $\alpha^{16}$?

Comment: Yes, and $\alpha^{16} = (\alpha^8)^2$ which is really easy to calculate, and $\alpha^{24} = (\alpha^8)^3$ which is also easy.

Comment: Thank you much appreciated.